# Excel Macro: for loop file to file

Tags: vba, excel

I do not know VBA yet I need to write a macro to optimize my work.
I'm looking for my code to loop through files and copy/paste the same column from each file onto an excel workbook (column by column). This is what I have so far (notice that I put "i" in the file name):

```
Sub NewMacro()

For i = 0 To 99

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
        "C:\User\Folder\file_up000i.txt", _
        Origin:=932, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    With ActiveWindow
        .Top = 6.25
        .Left = 53.5
    End With
    Windows("Book1").Activate
    With ActiveWindow
        .Top = 40.75
        .Left = 13
    End With
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("file_up000i.txt").Activate
    Range("C26").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book1").Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("file_up000i.txt").Activate
    With ActiveWindow
        .Top = 4
        .Left = -75.5
    End With
    ActiveWindow.Close

    Next i

End Sub
```

Clearly this does not work but I have no idea how else to go about it. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Where does the pasted content from the second and subsequent files go?  Are your files all named with zero-padded numbers ?  Is the 10th filename file_up00010.txt or file_up0010.txt ?

Comment: Further to Tim's queries, why are you looking to hardcode in 99 file names - the code will crash if these files don't all exist, or will be incomplete if there are more than 99 files. I would suggest using `Dir` to get the relevant names for a variable number of files, which can be sorted if order is important.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your files are named `file_up0000.txt`, `file_up0001.txt` ... `file_up0099.txt` here's a refactor of your macro

```
Sub NewMacro()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim shTxt As Worksheet
    Dim shDest As Worksheet
    Dim TxtName As String

    Set shDest = ActiveSheet
    For i = 0 To 99
        TxtName = "file_up" & Format(i, "0000")
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
            "C:\User\Folder\" & TxtName & ".txt", _
            Origin:=932, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
            xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
            Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        Set shTxt = Workbooks(TxtName & ".txt").Worksheets(TxtName)

        shTxt.[A3].Copy shDest.[B1]
        shTxt.Range(shTxt.[C26], shTxt.Range("C26").End(xlDown)).Copy shDest.[B2]
        shTxt.Parent.Close False
    Next i

End Sub
```